# Removing "afx.h" from external dependencies of a project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I have created a managed C++ project and under the MFC option in properties, I am using Windows Shared Libraries i.e. I dont want it to have any MFC properties.

When I copy any header file from another project into this new project, the external dependencies automatically gets filled. My project fails to build now because of the "afx.h" file present as a dependency eventhough no file including Stdafx.h includes afx.h

How do I remove afx.h from my dependencies?

Comment: Question isn't related to C#, removed tag.

Comment: You'll need to write better .h files.  Ones that contain *only* the declarations you need in your C++/CLI app and *none* of the MFC headers and classes.  Or just not bother since your final program really *does* have a dependency on MFC.